# The best way to install python 3 on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x

What is better way to install python3.3 on Mac OS X?

1. via homebrew
2. or via official installer in http://python.org/download/

Comment: Anyone has experience installing Python 3 alongside 2.7 from official installer? Homebrew seems to work fine on OS X, but keep in mind that [El Capitano has quirks](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/El_Capitan_and_Homebrew.md) wrt. System Integrity Protection and /usr/local/ directory which many set up Homebrew to use.

Comment: 5 years later... this is still a good question. Which is better homebrew or official installer?  I have a mac. I just went to python.org and installed 3.8.3 using the official PKG.  Then I have to run the certificate command. Everything worked perfectly!  To access pip, you prefix with python3, for example `python3 -m pip list` shows you the packages. And `python3 -m pip install matplotlib` will install a bunch of useful stuff.  I am use VSCode for the ide, and it works great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most people working in the Mac world will recommend homebrew or macports, I think.

I personally prefer homebrew. It doesn't install anything other than what you need, and it allows you an easy uninstall option, too. (`brew uninstall blah`). It also allows you to keep up with updates more easily.

Plus, (and I'm not sure if this is true with macports), you get pip for free.

---

That being said, you may have to get your hands dirty in your bash_profile and possibly your /usr directory---if you want to type python at the command line, and get your installed version of Python, you'll probably have to change some symbolic links.

I HATE/am not very good at fooling around with system settings, but I had my complete Python installation up and running in less than an hour, and it has been running without any issues for quite a while.